# I am getting the same latitude and longitude values everywhere

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I am developing an app to get the latitude and longitude of my current location. I noticed that the values are remaining the same if i move to another location. The codes to retrieve the location are in a service and I want to display it in an Acitivity's  Edittext box. I tried using shared preference in onLocationChanged method but the app is getting force closed. I am testing it on phone so I cannot post the Log. Can anyone tell me step by step what to do.
My codes are as follows:

GPSTracker.java

```
 public   class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 2; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

/*public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}*/
public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
/*public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}*/



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Double latitude1 = location.getLatitude();
    Double longitude1 = location.getLongitude();
    String t=String.valueOf(latitude1);
    SharedPreferences pref111=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor edtss=pref111.edit();

    edtss.putString("mynumbers",t);


    edtss.commit();
    //if(location != null){

        //latitude = location.getLatitude();
        //longitude = location.getLongitude();

          //currentlocation = "Location changed to lat: " + lat + "" + "lng: " + lng1 ;

           // Context context = getApplicationContext();
            //CharSequence text = currentlocation;
            //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+latitude+""+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //toast.show();


         // }

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

SaveLocationsActivity.java

```
public class SaveLocationsActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   SharedPreferences pref =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref111", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   String id=pref.getString("mynumbers", "Android");
```

}

Comment: Please upload the full code of `GPSTracker.java` with error log.

Comment: try this http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

Comment: Fine, but what about the error logs, where can I get it ?

Comment: I will post the log soon,pls check the updated GPSTracker.java

Comment: Well,its working fine without crashing on the emulator with the value of String id setting to Android. but it crashes on the phone